# "pdo_sqlite" is missing from my PHP installation - setting up Shlink

Tags: php, linux, rhel, rocky-os

So, I'm trying to selfhost Shlink, and I've followed the guide they provide [here](https://shlink.io/documentation/install-dist-file/). I'm running Rocky Linux 9 (RHEL9) and followed [this guide](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-php-8-on-rocky-almalinux/) to install PHP. I've installed all of the other dependencies but I can't find `pdo_sqlite`.

I've tried to install all of the following packages through `sudo dnf install`:

```
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlite3
php_sqlite
php_sqlite3
php8.2_sqlite
php8.2_sqlite3
php8_sqlite
php8_sqlite3
```

None of these have worked. Did some google searching as well and couldn't find anything, so figured I'd ask here.

EDIT: Here's the actual PHP error I'm getting.

Error 1: Shown whenever I run the installer for shlink

```php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Error 2: Shown when the installer completes

```php
  Error writing to "config/params/generated_config.php": file_put_contents(config/params/generated_config.php): Failed to open stream: No  
   such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try `php-pdo_sqlite`  Or just `install php-pdo` . The latter should install all PDO packages ..  The documentation can be found [HERE](https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/9/rockylinux-devel-x86_64/php-pdo-8.0.27-1.el9_1.x86_64.rpm.html)

Comment: Yeah, just says I already have the package installed.
``Package php-pdo-8.2.7-2.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.``